# phpword insert bullet list in a table

Tags: php, phpword

First of all sorry for my vary bad english (i'm Italian).
Hi, i have a problem with phpword library:
i would insert a bullet list in a cell but I just do not know how to do it.
This is my code:

```
<?php
include_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
include ('session_admin.php');
$class = $_SESSION['n_classe'];
include ('../conn_serv.php');

$phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();

$section = $phpWord->addSection();

$sectionStyle = $section->getStyle();

$sectionStyle->setMarginRight(\PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\Converter::cmToTwip(1));
$sectionStyle->setMarginLeft(\PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\Converter::cmToTwip(1));
$sectionStyle->setMarginTop(\PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\Converter::cmToTwip(1));
$sectionStyle->setMarginBottom(\PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\Converter::cmToTwip(1));


$fontStyle = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Style\Font();
$fontStyle->setBold(true);
$fontStyle->setName('Tahoma');
$fontStyle->setSize(12);
$myTextElement = $section->addText('RELAZIONE FINALE VISITA O VIAGGIO D ISTRUZIONE');
$myTextElement->setFontStyle($fontStyle);

$fancyTableStyleName = 'Fancy Table';
$fancyTableStyle = array('borderSize' => 1, 'borderColor' => 'd2d2d2', 'cellMargin' => 40, 'width' => 200 , 'alignment'  => \PhpOffice\PhpWord\SimpleType\JcTable::CENTER);
$fancyTableCellStyle = array('valign' => 'center');
$fancyTableFontStyle = array('bold' => true);
$phpWord->addTableStyle($fancyTableStyleName, $fancyTableStyle, $fancyTableFirstRowStyle);
$table = $section->addTable($fancyTableStyleName);

$table->addRow();
$table->addCell(20000)->addText('Classe/i ___________ sez. ____________');
$table->addRow();
$table->addCell(20000)->addText('Visita guidata/Viaggio d istruzione a:                                                              del: ');
$table->addRow();
$table->addCell(20000)->addText('Docente referente:');
$table->addRow();
$table->addCell(20000)->addText('Docenti accompagnatori:');
$table->addRow();



$table->addCell(20000)->addText('Realizzazione dell iniziativa: ');
//i would insert in this cell ^ the bullet list here below
$section->addListItem("secondo le previsioni");
$section->addListItem("parzialmente realizzata (motivare)");
$section->addListItem("non realizzata (motivare)");

$objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'Word2007');
$objWriter->save('Prova.docx');



//header("Location: stampa_proposte.php");?>
```

[The result that I will get is this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Ww53.png)

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 1):

just do it the way you add text to cell, so instead of current code:

```
$table->addCell(20000)->addText('Realizzazione dell iniziativa: ');
//i would insert in this cell ^ the bullet list here below
$section->addListItem("secondo le previsioni");
$section->addListItem("parzialmente realizzata (motivare)");
$section->addListItem("non realizzata (motivare)");
```

You can insert list items in table-cell this way:

```
$table_cell = $table->addCell(20000);//assign cell a variable
//add elements to cell. For square bullets refer documentation
$table_cell->addText('Realizzazione dell iniziativa: '); 
$table_cell->addListItem("secondo le previsioni",0);//0 is the list level
$table_cell->addListItem("parzialmente realizzata (motivare)",0);
$table_cell->addListItem("non realizzata (motivare)",0);
```